# custom loss to nullify a class contribution for the regression output in a keras multi task model

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I have a model which performs two basic tasks, a binary classification and a regression.
The contribution of one class has to be nullified for the regression task, while it's of course important for the classification.

Since a loss function in `keras` must have a signature like `myloss(y_true, y_pred)`, if I want to be aware of what class the actual sample belong to, I have to wrap the `myloss` function with something like:

```py
def wrap_loss(ctarget):
    def myloss(y_true, y_pred):
        # Create a mask to exclude samples of class 1
        mask = tf.where(tf.math.not_equal(ctarget, 1), 1.0, 0.0)
        squared_difference = tf.square(y_true - y_pred) * mask

        return tf.reduce_mean(squared_difference, axis=-1)

    return myloss
```

Since I have a `TFRecordDataset` in input, I define my model as

```py
model = keras.Model(
    inputs={
        "input1": input1,
        "input2": input2,
    },
    outputs={
        "regr_out": regr_output, 
        "class_id": class_output
    }
)
```

Now, ideally, I would like to specify losses while compiling my model, to separate the one for regression from the one for classification:

```py
model.compile(
    optimizer=opt,
    loss={
        "regr_out": wrap_loss(clf_labels),
        "class_id": keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
    },
    metrics={
        "regr_out": regr_metrics,
        "class_id": clf_metrics,
    },
)
```

and then call the `fit` method passing the dataset as input.

The problem is with the `clf_labels` variable: how can I pass it? A dataset is not subscriptable, and for the regression task I just have regression targets available.
The `tfrecord` parser I wrote returns the `class_id` in the second dictionary of the tuple, like:

```py
def parse_tfrec_for_training(example):
    [...]
    return (
        {'input1': example['input1'], 'input2': example['input2']},
        {'regr_out': example['regr_target'], 'class_id': example['class_id']}
    )
```

but I just cannot use `dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)['class_id']` to pass it to the `wrap_loss`.

Shall I write a custom train loop?
I would still like to use the `compile` and `fit` methods from `keras` though; I read the guides to [customise the fit function](https://keras.io/keras_core/guides/custom_train_step_in_tensorflow/) and to [write a custom loop](https://keras.io/guides/writing_a_training_loop_from_scratch/), but I'm not sure about how to implement this.